# Notificaciones en tiempo real codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Buen día, colegas.

Tengo una gran duda, ¿es posible enviar notificaciones en tiempo real después de insertar un registro en la Base de Datos en CodeIgniter 3?

De momento sólo funciona si se recarga la página, pero lo primordial sería que se envíen/muestren en seguida.

¿Alguna idea, opción que se les ocurra?

Comment: Para poder hacer ese tipo de operaciones en tiempo real debes implementar AJAX,